# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)}{\sin(\sin x)}$ without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Without using L'Hôpital's rule, find: 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)}{\sin(\sin x)}$$
>   I know that the answer is $0$.

My attempt:

I tried by using the half-angle formula, $$\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos A}{2}},$$ but I've couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you know Taylor polynomials? If not, you might want to use $\cos x = (\cos x - 1)+1$ and $\sin x = x\frac{\sin x}x$.

Comment: I'm not able to use Taylor polynomials.

Comment: As a hint, I'm not sure if this helps without L'Hopital, but the limit should be equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2\sin(x)}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{x}\right)}}{\sin{\left(\sin{x}\right)}}}&=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{x}\right)}}{\sin{\left(\sin{x}\right)}}}\\ &=\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\times\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^{2}}\times\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{x}\right)}}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\cos{x}}\times\frac{x}{\sin{x}}\times\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin{\left(\sin{x}\right)}}\right)}\\ &=0\times\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1\times 1\\ &=0\end{aligned}

Because $$ \lim_{\textrm{stuff}\to 0}{\frac{\sin{\left(\mathrm{stuff}\right)}}{\mathrm{stuff}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}=1 $$

And $$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^{2}}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^{2}}=\frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Thank you so much! That is the kind of solution that I was looking for. What an elegant approach!

Comment: You can replace the "stuff" by a single letter variable like $x, t$ etc and let the readers know about the law for limit of composite functions.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the limit as a product like so:

$$L = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{\sin( \sin x)} \cdot\frac{x}{\sin x} \cdot \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)}{x}$$

If the limits exist individually then the limit of their product will be the product of their limits. The first two limits are $1$, giving us that

$$L = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x) - \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos 0)}{x-0} \equiv \Bigr(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)\Bigr)'\Bigr|_{x=0} = 0$$

by the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Very nice approach! It's an elegant solution. However, I'm not able to use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @Gershgorin That's okay, CHAMSI has a really cool way of dealing with the $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x)$ term

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than the limit itself, compose Taylor series
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos (x))=\frac{\pi  x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi  x^4}{48}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sin(\sin(x))=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{10}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos (x)) } {\sin(\sin(x)) }=\frac{\frac{\pi  x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi  x^4}{48}+O\left(x^6\right) } {x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{10}+O\left(x^6\right) }=\frac{\pi  x}{4}+\frac{\pi  x^3}{16}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your observation! It could be very useful not just for this exercise, but for other limits.